# COUNTIF and AND

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2003, countif

I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets `Master` and `Results`. `Master` contains 'Date' in column A and Text Field 'Reason' in column B. In `Results`, the user will enter a Start and End date, I need to count the number of results in `Master` that are between the dates and have specific text in the 'Reason' column.

As I am only using *Excel 2003*, I think I can only achieve this by using COUNTIF and AND together, but I can't seem to write the correct formula, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple ways to do this with what Excel 2003 offers you: array formulas or a helper column.

```
[Master]
Date       Reason HelperColumn
2014-01-01 A      0
2014-02-01 B      0
2014-03-01 A      1
2014-04-01 A      1
2014-05-01 B      0
2014-06-01 A      0

[Results]
From:      2014-02-01
To:        2014-05-01
Reason:    A
Count:     2
```

**First example: array formulas**

The formula for the count would be:

```
{=SUM(IF(Master!A2:A7>=B1,1,0)*IF(Master!A2:A7<=B2,1,0)*IF(Master!B2:B7=B3,1,0))}
```

To use array formulas enter the formula without curly braces and press [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER] to submit the formula. More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).

**Second example: helper column**

Alternatively you could add a helper column on the Master sheet. This column would display a 1 if the current row matches the search criteria and 0 otherwise. Then you can get the count by using a regular `SUM` on the helper column.

Formula for helper column:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=Results!$B$1;A2<=Results!$B$2;B2=Results!$B$3);1;0)
```

And for the count in the Results sheet:

```
=SUM(Master!C2:C7)
```

Comment: Third way: `SUMPRODUCT` with a syntax close to your `SUM` example but without multiple `IF`s and no array formula: `=SUMPRODUCT((Master!A2:A7>=B1)*(Master!A2:A7<=B2)*(Master!B2:B7=B3))`

Answer (score 0):

@hsan, thanks for pointing that out. Please note then, that my code below is for Excel 2007+.

```
My Masters tab:

Date    Reason
10/07/2014  a
10/07/2014  b
10/07/2014  a
11/07/2014  d
11/07/2014  a
12/07/2014  b
13/07/2014  c


My Results tab:
s.Date  10/07/2014
e.Date  11/07/2014

Search  a

Count   3
```

The s.Date and e.Date are my start and endates and Search is the text search for reason (very simple 1 char match).

The formulae for the Count field is:

```
=COUNTIFS(Master!$A$2:$A$8,">="&B1,Master!$A$2:$A$8,"<="&B2,Master!$B$2:$B$8,Result!B4)
```

Notice how i'm using countIFS (not if) and i'm constructing the between dates syntax in condition 1 & 2 and then filtering on the search in condition 3.

You might need to adjust the third condition if you want to do more indepth searching.

Comment: Unfortunately Excel 2003 doesn't know `COUNTIFS`.